# How to append objects on a file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, object, append

I'm trying to make a small program inJava in which I need to save An array of objects on a file. I was looking for how to do this and I found the next code:

```
    //this is the array that will be stored
    private Atributtes list[]=new Atributtes [100];

    /*
    this is the way i save the data in the array,i always save them in
    index 0,and i made a for to put away the previous data because always
    there will have data in index 0
    */

    for (int i = totalElments; i>0; i--){
    list[i] = list[i-1];        
    }

    list[0]=new Atributtes ("Atributtes data");
    save.storeInfile(list);
    totalElments++;





private static final String filename="file.obj";

public void storeInfile(Object array[]){
    try{
        FileOutputStream file= new FileOutputStream(filename,true);
        ObjectOutputStream object= new ObjectOutputStream(file);
        object.writeObject(array);
        object.close();
        file.close();
        System.out.println("recording successfully");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
    }catch(Exception exceccao){
        System.out.println("recording wasn't successfull");
    }
}
```

My problem now is that when I want to save the same Array of objects but with another data,or when I reopen the file, the first data that was in the file is overwritten.

Note1:i was said to put the true boolean on FileoutPutSTream,but when i put it the recording doesn't happen anymore,but when i remove the true boolean the recording happens but with overwritten data always.

Note2: I've read about FileWriter and the PrintWriter, but I need to write only Objects, not Strings.thanks!!!!

Could someone tell how to append this new data on the file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
FileOutputStream file= new FileOutputStream(filename);
```

to this

```
FileOutputStream file= new FileOutputStream(filename, true)
```

The true stands for append enable or disable. In default it is disabled.

Comment: HI Isuru Dilshan,i've done what you sugested but now the recording doesn't happen,it only happens when i remove the true.

Comment: try to flush after writing. object.flush();

Comment: @IsuruDilshan `close()` calls `flush()`

Comment: @RALPHBURAIMO I ran your code using `String` instead of `Attributes`. Every time I run it, it appends an "Attribute data" to the file. I know this because I opened the file after each run and counted them manually. If you don't see the same, maybe something is wrong with your `for-loop` where you do this `list[i] = list[i-1];`. Perhaps you should your code on DEBUG mode to figure out what your code is doing.